# Sizing QWebView with expanding window

Tags: qt, qwebview

How would i go about sizing the QWebView window with the size of the window? Right now i see i can only give it certain dimensions, but how can i make it 100% width and 100% height, and change as i make a window bigger or smaller?

Basically if i was to resize, it would resize the QWebview as well. How do i go about this?

I see there is size dimensions but i dont see how to have it resize based on the window app.

[image: look here]

Answer (score 1):

Add your `QWebView` inside a layout.

```
QWebView *webView = new QWebView;
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
this->centralWidget()->setLayout(layout);
layout->addWidget(webView);
```

You can read more about [layout management here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/layout.html).