# Resize a QWebView and a QMessagebox according to the QMainWindow's size

Tags: c++, qt, webview, qwidget

I am new to QT. I made an application for Windows which contains a `QWebView` and a `QMessageBox`. I want to resize these two according to the size of my `QMainwindow`. For example, if the main window's size is `300*200`, then the size of `QWebView` and `QMessageBox` should be the same. Plus, I want to be able to resize it when I am running my application.

Can someone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should make your `QMessageBox` and your `QWebView` children widgets of your `QMainWindow`. You should have something like this in your `.cpp` file :

```
MyApp::MyApp(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    mView = new QWebView(this);
    mMessageBox = new QMessageBox(this);
    // some other code
}
```

with `mView` and `mMessageBox` private elements of your `.h` file.

And for the size, if you don't specify anything, you should be able to resize it as you want. Or if you want to try a fixed size, just add this line instead of `//some other code` :

```
this->setFixedSize(300,200);
```

Comment: I have added  QWebView and  QMessageBox using design(mainwindow.ui). so is their any method using which i can set these    things dynamically.

Comment: I don't understand : where do you use QMessageBox and QWebView? Directly in your `.ui` file?

Comment: In QT .ui file. using drag and drop i have create webview geometry ((0*0),(500,600)) and  using ui->webview->load(URL) i am loading the URL. now web page is load on QWebView. But when i re-size the running application. the QwebView size remain unchanged. So is there any method to re-size QwebView at run time.

Comment: Mmh ok I see. You need to define a layout for your widget. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216365/sizing-qwebview-with-expanding-window) :)

Comment: i tried with example and its working fine.  Can we achieve the same using QT Designer. I tried a lot but still not able to find the solution in QT designer.

Comment: Yes, of course. When you launch Designer, on the left, you should have a list of layout availables. Just drag and drop them to your main window, and then you put your widgets in the layout. When you will try to change the layout size, the size of the widgets in the layout will change too!